# linker errors compiling Magick++ code using cmake

Tags: cmake, magick++

I'm not sure if I'm missing something in my CMakeLists.txt or what. But when I try to compile my program after running cmake, I am getting:

```
'undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::Geometry(unsigned long, unsigned long, long, long, bool, bool)'
```

My CMakeLists.txt includes:

```
add_definitions(-DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16)
add_definitions(-DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0)
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(makethumbnail ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES} )
```

And the weird thing is that JetBrains CLion builds it just fine, but I get the error if I try to create my own build directory running cmake ../ then make.

What am I missing?

This is on an ubuntu 19.04.3 with gcc 7.4.0

Comment: What is the output when you run `cmake ..`? Can you add this output to your post? What does it print if you add `message("ImageMagick_LIBRARIES: ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES}")` to your CMake file?

Comment: the only think in it I see related to ImageMagick is a single line: "Found ImageMagick: /usr/lib/libMagick++.so (found version "6.9.7-4") "

Comment: This is a ImageMagick-7 portability issue. Looks like CLion was using ImageMagick-6, and cmake found ImageMagick-7.

Comment: interesting - how does ImageMagick-7 define the sizes for resizing?